# ¿Como hacer para que codigo de php no sea renderizado como una cadena de texto atraves de javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Buen dia, todo mi codigo esta funcionando bien, el unico problema es que necesito que cuando mi funcion ejecute esta linea: `n[a].value = "<?php echo $tablas["+a+"][0]; ?>";` no renderize el codigo php como una cadena de caracteres sino que escriba el codigo en php para ser posteriormente ejecutado y que pueda tomar el valor correspondiente dentro del arreglo. aqui esta el codigo de la funcion completa:

```
for(a=0; a<k.length; a++){
        console.log(a);
        n[a] = document.createElement("INPUT");
        n[a].id = "n"+a;
        n[a].value = "<?php echo $tablas["+a+"][0]; ?>";
        console.log(n[a]);
        document.getElementById("divVars").appendChild(n[a]);
    }
```

A parte si en lugar de utilizar un `<input>` utilizo un `<p>` y en lugar de usar `value` utilizo `innerHTML` el codigo php aparece comentado. ¿Como puedo hacer para que el codigo sea ejecutado?
El archivo php es este:

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","capacitacion");
    $consulta = "SHOW TABLES FROM capacitacion";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    if($resultado){
        $tablas = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado);
    }
    else{
        echo 'error';
    }
    //Nueva parte.
    $j = count($tablas);
    $examenes = array();

    for($i=0; $i<$j; $i++){
        array_push($examenes, $tablas[$i][0]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente? Ten en cuenta que PHP trabaja del lado del servidor y Javascript trabaja del lado del cliente (para poner un ejemplo: el servidor es tu casa y el cliente es cualquiera que anda por la calle). Considera que no puedes (a menos que recurras a soluciones algo oscuras), mandar a ejecutar en el servidor cualquier cosa que sea escrita en un `input` del cliente. Eso puede ser muy peligroso. Explica qué quieres hacer con esto: `n[a].value = "<?php echo $tablas["+a+"][0]; ?>";` y quizá podamos sugerirte una solución segura.

Comment: Buenas tardes, A.Cedano. Lo que estoy haciendo es una plataforma para hacer examenes de opcion multiple. Ahorita estoy haciendo una seccion para cargar los examenes guardados, es por eso que la vez pasada estaba haciendo un script que pudiera crear tablas en mi BDD las cuales seran populadas con preguntas y respuestas respectivamente. El dia de hoy estoy haciendo un codigo que cargue estos examenes, por lo que en esta fase estoy haciendo una consulta a la base de datos para cargar los nombres de las tablas, los cuales son los examanes que estan guardados.

Comment: Ok. Entonces no hay ninguna duda de que necesitas usar Ajax para esto. Con Ajax mandarías a buscar los datos al servidor, los recibes en la respuesta y actualizar el contenedor del cliente con esos datos. Eso no es solamente seguro, sino elegante además, porque todo se hace en background, sin tener que recargar la página. Ajax es tu solución.

Comment: Okay, estoy seguro que cuando haga cosas mas complejas me vere en la necesidad de usar otras tecnicas y lenguajes de programacion, pero ahorita prefiero usar algo mas limitado para tener mas practica, sin embargo, lo que necesito ahorita saber es, como hacerle para que los codigos php cuando son insertados en el html atraves de javascript no aparescan comentados o como cadenas de caracteres.

Comment: en contraste en mi index tengo esta linea la cual funciona sin ningun problema ```<input id="cantidadDeExamenes" value="<?php echo count($tablas); ?>">```

Comment: El problema seguramente sea porque el código php que está puesto ahí, esté dentro de un archivo .js. Si es así fallará ya que el interprete de php en XAMPP, que es lo que creo que estás usando por intuición, solo cogé los ficheros .php para ser interpretados. Si es así, la solución es cambiar el código de JavaScript al .php y ponerlo entre etiquetas <script></script>.

Comment: Como mencionó A. Cedano, está el código que es ejecutado en el servidor y por otro lado el código que es ejecutado en el cliente. No puedes desde JavaScript ejecutar instrucciones PHP. Lo que puedes hacer es ejecutar el PHP en el servidor y que te genere el JavaScript ya con esos valores.

Comment: Hola Marci, estoy usando WAMP server, precisamente, mi archivo index es de extension .php. Ademas, dentro del cual utilizo algunas lineas de codigo php para traerme valores de algunas variables en dicho archivo, en este caso necesito traerme los valores de los indices del arreglo para usarlos dentro del html.

Comment: Es importante que entiendas lo que te comenté antes. Este código: `<input id="cantidadDeExamenes" value="<?php echo count($tablas); ?>">` es totalmente diferente a este: `"<?php echo $tablas["+a+"][0]; ?>";` ¿Por qué?  En el 1º, todo lo que hay entre las etiquetas de PHP es código PHP, pero en el 2º la variable `a` es del entorno de Javascript y eso cambia todo, por lo mismo que ya te expliqué antes. Aparte de eso, Ajax no es un lenguaje, es parte de Javascript y tú ya estás usando Javascript. Intentando lograr algo como lo que pretendes no añade nada al aprendizaje ...

Comment: ... al contrario, te conduce por un camino de aprendizaje oscuro y peligroso, totalmente fuera del estándar que no sirve para nada más que para perder el tiempo o para poner en riesgo tu entorno. Este tipo de procesos se hacen por medio de Ajax. OJO, ¡Ajax se aprende en un día!, es algo muy sencillo, basta con comprender cómo funciona. Aquí hay varias respuestas que lo explican.

Comment: Okay si entiendo eso, pero aun asi sigo creyendo que hay algo mas que se puede hacer ya que cuando se corre la linea ```n[a].value = "<?php echo $tablas["+a+"][0]; ?>";``` se muestra como texto dentro de un input y la variable a toma el valor que le corresponde dentro del documento.

Comment: Lo acabo de pillar jajajajaja. Son la comillas dobles. "<?php echo $tablas["+a+"][0]; ?>". Prueba a usar '<?php echo $tablas["+a+"][0]; ?>'. Al usar comillas dobles para la indicar en Js que es un string y la doble comilla de la tabla, pueden estar incidiendo una sobre la otra.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que estás exagerando un poco. Él debe estar intentando realizar esa solución que menciona porque no tiene claro la diferencia entre ejecutar el cliente y ejecutar en el servidor, es algo que cuesta comprender al inicio. No es que él quiera perder tiempo a propósito como dices. Además, por el hecho de utilizar Ajax, su aplicación no necesariamente será más segura, al contrario deberá de prestar más atención a proteger las peticiones y el api expuesto. Aún así, sí considero que Ajax sería la mejor implementación a seguir para obtener datos desde el servidor.

Comment: @GerardoTopete es posible que edites tu pregunta agregando todo el código del archivo php? Tal vez con eso te podríamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: @Jemonge no he dicho ni querido decir que esté queriendo perder el tiempo. Si lees los comentarios, he intentado explicar de forma sencilla la diferencia entre cliente y servidor. En cualquier caso, no he escrito nada aquí con ánimo de ofender, sino de ayudar, lamento si se ha podido interpretar de esa manera. En un comentario Gerardo explicó lo que quiere lograr y no hay mejor solución que Ajax.

Comment: Si se la diferencia entre cuando algo se hace en el servidor y otra del lado del cliente.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es mostrar la lista de tablas que te genera esa consulta en el servidor, lo más simple es usar Ajax o bien incorporar ese código en tu página del cliente (si ésta es extensión .php)  y renderizar todo in situ. Todo depende de si quieres algo dinámico, como pasarle el nombre de la base de datos al servidor para que busque su lista de tablas y cosas así.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! Creo que tu problema está en que estás ingresando la variable a javascript como cadena de texto. Para que el código en PHP se ejecute, deberías quitar las comillas:

```
for(a=0; a<k.length; a++){
    console.log(a);
    n[a] = document.createElement("INPUT");
    n[a].id = "n"+a;
    n[a].value = <?php echo $tablas["+a+"][0]; ?>;
    console.log(n[a]);
    document.getElementById("divVars").appendChild(n[a]);
}
```

Espero que te sirva.